# Subspace Relating with Direct Sum

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

I'm having a silly doubt studying linear algebra, can someone help me out? Let me first state it formally.

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{K}$-vector space. Let $W,V_1,\ldots V_k$ be subspaces of $V$ such that
$$ V= V_1\oplus V_2\oplus \ldots \oplus V_k.$$

I want to know if the statement

$$ W = (W\cap V_1)\oplus (W\cap V_2)\oplus\ldots\oplus(W\cap V_k).$$

is true!

The inclusion "$\supseteq$" is trivial. On the other hand, I don't know how to show "$\subseteq$". I thought that a proof by induction would help me here but couldn't think of anything useful.

Does anybody even know if the result is true?

Comment: I think it is true, but I am not sure that the proof is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

It is false.

Let $k=2,\ a\in V_1,\,b\in V_2$ nonzero vectors and $W:=\mathrm{span}(a+b)$.

Then $W\cap V_i=\{0\}$, else $b\in V_1$ [resp. $a\in V_2$] would follow.

Comment: Tks for the counterexample! Do you know more datails? For example, some hypothesis under which the result is true?

Comment: For example, if $W$ is of the form $\sum_jV_{i_j}$.